# Finding the gradient of $(,)=\max\{||,||\}$ for $|x|=|y|$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, scalar-fields, subgradient, non-smooth-analysis

We have the function $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ given by

$$f(x,y) := \max \left\{ |x|, |y| \right\}$$

Let $C := \left\{ (x,y) \mid |x|=|y| \right\}$. Given point $(x,y) \in C$, how can I find the gradient $\nabla f(x,y)$ if it exists?

But I don't think the function is differentiable in $|x|=|y|$, so I can't find $\nabla f(x,y)$ for $(x,y) \in C$, or what? Are there other points where $f$ is not differentiable?

Comment: Mother question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4072027/339790

Comment: There are only two cases to consider: $\nabla f(x,x)$ and $\nabla f(x,-x)$.

Comment: @Geoffrey Trang If $y=-x$ then $f(x,-x)=f(x,x)$ therefore function is not differentiable if $||=||$ and we can't find the gradient?